# Cutting a speed-adjusted clip distorts audio/video alignment in Video Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Blender Version 2.82a

I am combining clips that I recorded with my phone using both front and back cameras. This means that I must adjust the video speed on some to align with the audio because the front camera records at 60fps and the back camera records at 30fps. One clip,slowed down from 60fps to 30fps I am trying to cut a few seconds off of.

I adjust the speed of the individual clips using the Add>Effect Strip>Speed Control.

When I perform a hard cut (shift+k) on the audio and video, the video in the clip slows down relative to the audio. When I perform a soft cut (k) on the audio and video, the video speeds up relative to the audio.

How do I cut the clip so that the audio and video stay aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but I found a work-around.

I opened the clip that I needed to shorten on its own, cut out what I needed, rendered it and then opened up the new version in the full video I was working on. Because it was already shortened, when I applied the speed change, it fit where I needed it and I was done.

Answer (score 0):

looks like blender can only speed control video, but no audio.

[image]

but you can change the speed of the sound by pitch:

[image]

Comment: My problem is not changing the speed of the audio, it is that the audio and video track de-synchronize after I cut them. The audio track is fine, I don't want to change its speed, in fact this would be bad because it is speaking. I need to cut the video (with the audio) and then re-sync the video to the audio